# Dual booting starting without any OS

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I don't have any OS on my computer right now, but I have 2 500gb hard drives and would like to duel boot windows 7. I would like to have about 250gb for windows and the other 750gb go to ubuntu. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Install Windows first. Ubuntu will recognise the existing Windows and happily install alongside it. If you do it the other way Windows will overwrite the boot loader and you will only have Windows.  This can be fixed but if you have no OS at present Windows first will be easier

Answer (score 0):

You need to partition your drive(s)

The easy part is that once you've partitioned, you can choose the 250GB partition for Windows and the 750GB to Ubuntu.

Windows:
Once you do that you can buy a Windows install disk. And it should ask what partition you want it to install to.

And for Ubuntu:
Easy you just need to get the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on the downloads page. When you run the installer, it  should ask you how much memory and on what drive Ubuntu is going to take. And since you have no OS's you might have to get a boot-able disk.

(or first install windows, *then* run the 64-bit install program in the *booted* Windows

Comment: With 2 drives I would install Windows to sda, and install Ubuntu to sdb. And keep each systems boot loader on that drive. You do have to use Something Else with Ubuntu to have the choice on where to install the grub2 boot loader. Or just disconnect Windows drive and use auto install. Then you can copy some Windows data to Ubuntu drive and Ubuntu data to Windows drive as backups. You would want extra data partitions to support that.